# R Time Series Data, Group by Positive Ratio

Tags: r, time-series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X2XL.png)

How can I group the positive tweets ratio (Positive Tweets/Total Tweets) by month?

Comment: Is it year month or just month?

Answer (score 1):

We may need to convert the 'Time' to `Datetime` class, extract the `month`, use that as grouping variable and `summarise` to get the `mean` of logical `vector`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(month = month(ymd_hm(Time))) %>%
     summarise(Ratio = mean(Emotion == 'Positive'))
```

In case, it is year and month, change the `group_by` to return the 'year', 'month' with `format` or `strftime`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(yearmonth = format(ymd_hm(Time), "%Y-%m")) %>%
   summarise(Ratio = mean(Emotion == "Positive"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you comment. It still shows the following error:Error: Incomplete expression: data > 2roup_by(month = month(ymd_hm(data$Time)) >Ratio = mean(Emotion == 'Positive'))



ummarise(Ratio = mean(Emotion == 'Positive'))

Comment: @XupinZhang sorry, there is a missing `)`. fixed